# How to change Bluemix white labeling (branding changes)

Tags: ibm-cloud, white-labelling

Provide the how to change white labeling (branding changes) in bluemix.
We are trying to change Blue mix headers and home page for particular space.

Comment: Please, give more information about what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

A new version of the Bluemix console launched this week, with a white background and updated headers. The URL is https://console.ng.bluemix.net (for the US-South region - swap out the ng for eu-gb or au-syd if you are in a different region). The old console is being phased out. If you start at this new URL, you should always get the new console branding for whatever space you are using.